# How to use the "nextToken" parameter to test Pagination?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I am working with a sample of graphql query which I want to further bind to a FlatList object in a React-Native app. But I am still struggling to understand what I should pass on then nextToken parameter in order to get a slice of objects destined to a second page...

Tried to pass the next or last id or index, but it didn't work - it asks me to provide a valid nextToken, which I don't know what kind of data it is.

I'm running through AppSynch console.

My query:

```
query ListResources(
  $nextTokenPlants: String = "Orange Tree"
  $limitPlants: Int = 3
) {
  listResources {
    items {
      id
      name
      Plants(limit: $limitPlants, nextToken:$nextTokenPlants) {
        items {
          id
          name
          filterName
          description
          bath
          tea
          insence
          children
        }
        nextToken
      }
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listResources": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "361dee16-d567-41ed-b1d4-9baa4a7ffdcc",
          "name": "Plantas",
          "Plants": null
        }
      ],
      "nextToken": null
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "listResources",
        "items",
        0,
        "Plants"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:UserIllegalArgumentException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 9,
          "column": 7,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "com.amazonaws.deepdish.common.pagination.InvalidPaginationTokenException: Invalid pagination token given."
    }
  ]
}
```

I expected to get a list of 3 of the itens stored on "Plants", starting from the "Orange Tree" onwards... Could anyone pls shed some light on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nextToken` is a String that you get in the response when you send a request, looks like

> 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

and it has nothing to do with your table keys.

Let me explain now how does it work:

1. When you send the request for the first time, you don't send `nextToken` since you don't have it and then you get the first portion of your data.
   When you receive that first portion, if there exist more data, you get `nextToken` in the response.
2. Now, you have `nextToken`, you send another request to get the 2nd portion of your data. You should send that token in the request, so your backend knows from where to start.
3. You get your 2nd portion of data and a new `nextToken` if there is still some data to fetch (then you need to repeat step 2) or `null` in `nextToken` if there is no more data.

I hope that it's clear now